# Child process ignores SIGQUIT if started from Java

Tags: java, linux, signals

Take this simple example:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sleep 1000");

        // This is just so that the JVM does not exit
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 1000);
    }
}
```

I am running this on Linux using openjdk6. If I try to send a `SIGQUIT` signal to the "sleep" process, it ignores it. Other signals (`SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` etc) all work fine, but `SIGQUIT` is ignored. If I just run `sleep 1000` from a shell without using Java, then `SIGQUIT` is handled properly.

Why is the behaviour different?

Comment: I guess you would have to write a handler for the signal so that your program actually "quits"

Comment: No. Quitting is the default action for `SIGQUIT`. As I say in the question, if I just run the command from a shell without using Java, it handles `SIGQUIT` properly (== it quits)

Comment: Probably it's that _sleep_ actually implements the handler for SIGQUIT and that's why it actually "quits". https://superuser.com/questions/352147/what-does-kill-3-mean

Comment: But you're not running it from a shell when you run it from Java, that may be the difference. Try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 1000"});` and see if that can be killed with SIGQUIT.

Comment: @Edmundo: No. Terminating the process is the default action for `SIGQUIT`. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: Good catch. Just tried that; same result, though. It sill ignores `SIGQUIT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass java the `-Xrs` option. I have tested your program with and without the option. Without the option, SIGQUIT is blocked; with it, the signal is not blocked and the sleep process is terminated when I send it a SIGQUIT signal.

The closest explanation I can find about what's going on is in the [OpenJDK 6 java(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/java-java-1.6.0-openjdk) man page:

> Sun's JVM catches signals to implement shutdown hooks for abnormal JVM termination. The JVM uses SIGHUP, SIGINT, and SIGTERM to initiate the running of shutdown hooks.
>
> The JVM uses a similar mechanism to implement the pre-1.2 feature of dumping thread stacks for debugging purposes. Sun's JVM uses SIGQUIT to perform thread dumps.
>
> Applications embedding the JVM frequently need to trap signals like SIGINT or SIGTERM, which can lead to interference with the JVM's own signal handlers. The -Xrs command-line option is available to address this issue. **When -Xrs is used on Sun's JVM, the signal masks for SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGHUP, and SIGQUIT are not changed by the JVM, and signal handlers for these signals are not installed.**

Comment: OK. Looks like `-Xrs` does the trick. But why is this happening? Even if the JVM sets up a signal handler for SIGQUIT, that should be reset to the default action when starting a child process via `fork`+`exec`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I am accepting this answer but have also posted a slightly different question based on this one; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982014/cant-set-signal-handler-for-sigquit-in-child-process-started-from-java

Comment: It looks like when the series of calls to Runtime, ProcessBuilder, ProcessImpl, and UNIXProcess are made, SIGQUIT is blocked and remains blocked (and blocked signals remain blocked across fork and exec). I haven't looked at the code in detail; the fact that it isn't explicitly unblocked in UNIXProcess may just be an oversight.

Comment: Makes sense. But then it should be unblocked if I try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982014/cant-set-signal-handler-for-sigquit-in-child-process-started-from-java)....

Comment: This no longer seems to work. Is there any sort of workaround for this?